# Convert 3d matrix into a data frame

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a 3-dimensional matrix with dimensions 9x3x12 (just a sample). This matrix values are temperatures recorded at different latitudes(3), longitudes(9) and timestamps(12).

On the other hand, I have latitudes, longitudes and timestamps as vectors. Like...
lat = [13, 15...]
lon = [100, 105, 109, 111.....]
timestamp = ["1992061000" "1992061100" "1992061200" "1992061300" "1992061400"....]

My intention is to create a dataframe that has 9x3x12 rows where each row corresponds to one temperature value and has four columns namely lat, lon, timestamp and temperature.

Can anyone suggest an optimal way to do this without too many loops. One way would be to loop through the vectors and matrix after creating an empty dataframe but i fear it isn't all that optimal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `expand.grid()` for combination of dimensions and `as.vector` to get data as a vector.

Pay attention to order of dimentions!

```
dim1 <- c('a', 'b')
dim2 <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
dim3 <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

data <- array(1:24, c(2,3,4), dimnames = list(dim1, dim2, dim3))
data

cbind(expand.grid(dim1,  dim2, dim3), val = as.vector(data))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so simple. Works like a charm.